What happened to the Windows feature that prevented applications to steal the focus?
Some years ago, it was useless to use an API such as SetForegroundWindow to force some Window to the top of the Z-Order: the only result you got was a blinking icon in your taskbar, as stealing focus is bad.
The only solution was then to use various tricks, such as Raymond's famous technique based on a Hot Key.
Today I did a simple POC and discovered that my program IS capable of stealing focus, without any tricks! What is this witchcraft?
Note: my HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\ForegroundLockTimeout is at 30d40 (200s)
Windows 11 Enterprise 23H2
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Starting..." << std::endl;
    if (argc != 3) {
usage:
        std::cout << "Usage: StealFocus -h [Handle value in hex]" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    wchar_t* pszSwitch = argv[1];
    if (wcscmp(pszSwitch, L"-h") != 0) {
        std::cout << "Bad switch." << std::endl;
        goto usage;
    }

    wchar_t* pszArg = argv[2];
    long lHandle = wcstol(pszArg, nullptr, 16);
    if (lHandle == 0) {
        std::cout << "Invalid hex value" << std::endl;
        goto usage;
    }

    std::cout << "We will TRY to steal the focus in 10 seconds..." << std::endl;
    Sleep(10000);

    HWND hWndTarget = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(IntToPtr(lHandle));
    BOOL bSuccess = SetForegroundWindow(hWndTarget);
    if (bSuccess != FALSE) {
        std::cout << "Success!" << 
        return 0;
    }
}


Hmm. Isn't this a program that has focus, and is therefore able to give it away? Although it's hard to tell what's going on with all the bogus type declarations and ensuing casts.

@DavidHeffernan This is why I wait 10 seconds... This allows me to put the Focus in Excel. What bogus type declarations? Works wonderfully, stealing the focus...

It works as expected for me, ie if some other application has the focus, this other app keeps it. If the console app has the focus, it works. You're probably in one of the cases described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks
